# Justify bootstrap navbar links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to make the links in the navbar stretch to the full length of the navbar. I am looked around here and found some useful information but cannot get it to work properly

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-links">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>

        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsable-links">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

This is my navbar. I tried to add nav-justified to my ul tag and set the following CSS

```
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
```

this kind of worked but it makes all the links drop down because of the brand i think

[image]

I took the home button out of the header and added it to a li in my ul (i don't want it to collapse but thought i would test it) and that kind of works too

[image]

The problem with the above is that all seems to be aligned to the right and i need it aligned to the left. I am struggling with this and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I managed to get this to work by removing navbar-nav from the ul and using nav-justified on its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first i fixed this by changing my code from:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified">
```

to:

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified">
```

This seemed to work however it messed up alot of the formatting which is taken care of by the navbar-nav class.

After looking at the boostrap css file and playing wiht a couple of classes i managed to solve the issue. The nav-justified was set to width 100% but due to some padding set in the navbar-nav class this didn't fit on one line anymore and was pushing the links down. using the code below i managed to resolve the issue

```
.nav-justified {
width: 98%;
}
.nav-justified > li {
float: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .nav-justified {
        width: 97%;
    }
}
```

Now everything works as it should.